# Upload files using ajax in struts 1.2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, struts

I want to upload files using ajax in struts 1.2. If am using struts tags  then file has been uploaded successfully . But I want to send file from jQuery to Struts Action class using ajax .

Here is my ajax post request and this will get invoked when user hits send button,

```
var dataRow = {
            'title'    : $("#emailSubject").val(),
            'toAddress'; $("#toAddress").val(),
            'emailBody' :$("#emailBody").val()

        },

        $.ajax ({
            url :  //action class url
            type : POST,
            data : dataRow,
            success : function(response){

            }
        });
```

And my html has few input fields and file input field for file uploading (input type ="file").

I want to pass uploaded file details in the above ajax request.

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: What the difficulties are you experiencing?

Comment: I don't know how to send the file from jsp to struts action using Ajax

Comment: Have you checked the DWR Project that is Ajax being easy for Java? [DWR](https://java.net/projects/dwr)